# Cursor column index changes from phone to phone

Tags: android, orm, android-cursor

My application allows a user to call the most recent number that was called out. By hitting the "Call" button with an empty text box it will grab the latest Outgoing number in my ORM database. The issue however happens on only some phones.

When I pull my data I do so with the following code:

```
Dao<RecentCallsInfo, Integer> dao = null;
if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    dao = main.getDatabaseHelper().getRecentDataDao();
}

QueryBuilder<RecentCallsInfo, Integer> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.orderBy(RecentCallsInfo.RECENT_COLUMN_ID, false);
qb.where().eq(RecentCallsInfo.RECENT_COLUMN_CALL_TYPE, "Outgoing");

// when you are done, prepare your query and build an iterator
CloseableIterator<RecentCallsInfo> iterator = dao.iterator(qb.prepare());

// get the raw results which can be cast under Android
AndroidDatabaseResults results = (AndroidDatabaseResults)iterator.getRawResults();
Cursor c = results.getRawCursor();

if(c.moveToFirst()){
    if(!c.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM).isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Recent Record: \n Name:" + c.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_NAME) + 
        "\nNum:" + c.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM) + "\nNumType:" + c.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM_TYPE)+ 
        "\nCallType:" + c.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_CALL_TYPE));

        etcalle.setText(c.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM));
     }
 }

 //RecentQuery.COLUMN_NAME = 5
 //RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM = 6
 //RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM_TYPE = 0
 //RecentQuery.COLUMN_CALL_TYPE = 2
```

When I debug my `c` Cursor, it gives me these columns with these values

```
[recentNumberType, recentCallCost, recentCallType, recentCallerID, recentDate, recentName, recentNumber, _id]

Name:anthony
Num:(111) 111-1111
NumType:Mobile
CallType:Outgoing
```

When I get my `c` Cursor on another phone I get

```
[recentCallCost, recentCallType, recentCallerID, recentDate, recentName, recentNumber, recentNumberType, _id]

Name:(111) 111-1111
Num:Mobile
NumType:FREE
CallType:1867
```

So when I try and pull my data by index I get different values. Why does this happen? Both phones are Nexus 5 and on 4.4.2.

Any insight on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: why are you using hardcoded indices?

Comment: @pskink where do I hardcode indices? The RecentQuery comments are so people know what index I am pulling

Comment: so in "getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM)" RecentQuery.COLUMN_NUM is not a constant?  uppercase suggests so

Comment: Yes it is a constant. Is this bad practice? I was pretty sure this was ok because the columns shouldn't change

Comment: you should use getColumnIndex or getColumnIndexOrThrow,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns can "change". For example, consider this case.

- Version 1 of an app creates the T table, with columns `A, C`
- In version 2, you want to change the structure of the database. So you add the `B` column to your "create table" scripts. In new devices, this table will have columns `A, B, C`.
- However, in the onUpgrade() part, you just add column `B` (via `ALTER TABLE`), and the structure will end up as `A, C, B`.

In general it's a bad idea to use fixed ("integer") column indexes, unless you also specify which columns you want (i.e. not using `SELECT *`). Using `getColumnIndex()` (outside the loop) is safer.